# Errors when using "json_query"

Tags: ansible

When using `json_query` in Ansible, I got the below error when running my code.

The Python used in Ansible is 3.6.8, where I installed `jmespath` with the command: `pip install jmespath`. So this should not be the issue. The Ansible code should be fine as well.

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: no filter named 'json_query'. String: {{ jsondata | json_query(jmesquery) }}"
```

The following is the Ansible codes:

```yaml
---
- name: ReadJsonfile
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Display the JSON file content
  shell: cat config.json
  register: result

- name: save the JSON data to a Variable as a Fact
  set_fact:
    jsondata: "{{ result.stdout | from_json }}"

- name: setDomainName
  set_fact:
    domain_name: "{{ jsondata | json_query(jmesquery) }}"

  vars:
    jmesquery: 'domain.name'

- name: setDomainUsername
  set_fact:
    domain_username: "{{ jsondata | json_query(jmesquery) }}"

  vars:
    jmesquery: 'domain.user'

- name: setDomainPassword
  set_fact:
    domain_password: "{{ jsondata | json_query(jmesquery) }}"

  vars:
    jmesquery: 'domain.password'

- name: setadmin_Listenport
  set_fact:
    admin_ListenPort: "{{ jsondata | json_query(jmesquery) }}"

  vars:
    jmesquery: 'domain.admin.listenport'

- name: Debug the values
  debug: msg=" Admin Listen Port => {{ admin_ListenPort }}, DomainName => {{ domain_name }}, DomainUserName => {{ domain_username }} , Domain Password => {{ domain_password }}"
```

Answer (score 4):

From the error message, I suspect you are using ansible 2.10

The `json_query` filter is part of the `community.general` collection which needs to be installed separately starting from this version (this is clearly stated in the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-json-data-json-queries))

```
ansible-galaxy collection install community.general
```

---

That being said:

1. your actual jmespath queries will not return what you expect
2. using shell to get a file content from remote is a bad practice
3. that's lots of `set_facts` and `json_query` to simply get data that is readily available

Since [yaml is a strict superset of json](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/), any valid json is also a valid yaml. In your case, you only have to load the content of the file and you have the data.

One solution is to [`fetch`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fetch_module.html) the file locally and then use [`include_vars`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_vars_module.html).

In this particular case, using [`slurp`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/slurp_module.html#ansible-collections-ansible-builtin-slurp-module) looks like the best option.

This is what (I believe, since you did not provide an example) your config file looks like. I pushed that file in `/tmp/config.json` for my example.

```json
{
  "domain": {
    "name": "toto",
    "user": "doejohn",
    "password": "sosecret",
    "admin": {
      "listenport": 5501
    }
  }
}
```

This is the demo playbook

```yaml
---
- name: Load remote json content demo
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    config_file: /tmp/config.json

    # Of course the below vars will fire errors
    # if you call them before slurping data from remote.
    # Note: loading `data` in a jinja expression on its own
    # forces to transform it back rom string to json data.
    # You can accomplish the same result in one go
    # using the `from_json` filter
    # i.e. => domain: "{{ (slurped_config.content | b64decode | from_json).domain }}"
    data: "{{ slurped_config.content | b64decode }}"
    domain: "{{ data.domain }}"
    # Note2: the above will work and adapt to N hosts in your play: you will get
    # the correct data for each host in every task.

  tasks:
    - name: Slurp config file content
      slurp:
        src: "{{ config_file }}"
      register: slurped_config

    - name: Show result
      vars:
        message: |-
          name is: {{ domain.name }}
          user is: {{ domain.user }}
          password is: {{ domain.password }}
          port is: {{ domain.admin.listenport }}
      debug:
        msg: "{{ message.split('\n') }}"
```

which gives:

```
PLAY [Load remote json content demo] ******************************************************

TASK [Slurp config file content] **********************************************************
Wednesday 21 April 2021  17:57:47 +0200 (0:00:00.010)       0:00:00.010 ******* 
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Show result] ************************************************************************
Wednesday 21 April 2021  17:57:48 +0200 (0:00:00.199)       0:00:00.209 ******* 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "name is: toto",
        "user is: doejohn",
        "password is: sosecret",
        "port is: 5501"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   

Wednesday 21 April 2021  17:57:48 +0200 (0:00:00.027)       0:00:00.237 ******* 
=============================================================================== 
Slurp config file content ---------------------------------------------------------- 0.20s
Show result ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 0.03s
```

Comment: You solved the puzzle. Thanks a lot! The reason I wanted to get json_query done is because I thought it could provide me the solution for a task I am working on.  I will open up another question to explain the task.